# Exception for crispy form tags

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I am receiving error while trying to use crispy form tags as below

**Error during template redering**

for tag `{% crispy form form.helper %}`

template html file is as below

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
...
    {% crispy form form.helper %}
...
```

Forms.py contains something like this

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit
import floppyforms as forms

class SampleForm(forms.Form):
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try without from.

```
{% crispy form helper %}
```

Comment: Try {% crispy sample_form sample_form.helper %}

Answer (score -1):

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    [...]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-exampleForm'
        self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = 'submit_survey'

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

And then:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy example_form example_form.helper %}
```

This is from [Crispy forms documentation](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html)